# std::cin syntax when encounter EOF

Tags: c++, cin

This code is just to realize a function that when you input twice same strings,
the function stops.

```
string predata;
string c_data;  //current data

cout << "please input string data" << endl;

//loop
while (cin >> c_data) {

    if (c_data == predata) {
        cout << "the " << c_data << " is the same one" << endl;
        break;
    }   
    else {
        predata = c_data;
    }   

    cout << "please input next word" << endl;
}   

if (c_data != predata)
    cout << "there's no repeated word" << endl;
```

**Question**: When I use CTRL-D to stop cin, the c_data is not change, and it will never output *"there's no repeated word"*， so how can I decide the judgement ?

**PS**: This is one exercise in 《c++ primer》, and the code in answer book didn't solve the problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't too specific about what you've entered previously.  When `>>`
to a `std::string` fails, it leaves the right hand operand in an
unspecified state.  (And if this is actually the code in the book, I'd
throw the book away.)

The simplest solution here is just to use a flag:

```
std::string previous;
std::string current;
bool duplicateSeen = false;
std::cout << "Please input initial string" << std::endl;
std::cin >> previous;
if ( std::cin ) {
    //  Code needs at least one input to compare...
    while ( ! duplicateSeen && std::cin >> current ) {
        duplicateSeen = current == previous;
        previous = current;
        std::cout << "Please input the next word" << std::endl;
    }
}
if ( duplicateSeen ) {
    std::cout << '\"' << previous << "\" is duplicated" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "No repeated words" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Don't see the need for `if (std::cin )` (unless you want to report an error this just makes the code more complex to read).

Comment: Good point: any failure in the initial read of `previous` will cause the following read of `current` to fail, and since `duplicateSeen` will remain false, `previous` will never be accessed.  And removing the `if` will remove one level of nesting.

Comment: This code is not the code in the book , and it's not full version of my code , i just cut some parts. @JamesKanze

Answer (score 0):

I think when you hit `CTRL-D`, you interrupt running.

Try this:

```
while (cin >> c_data) {

if (c_data == "<EXIT>") break;

....
}
```

Comment: I know this method, but I just want to explore the characteristic of cin

Comment: @iverson you can check for some symbol for interrupt but you need `istream::get()` instead of `cin`

Answer (score 0):

This may be a solution:

```
c_data = "eof is setted";

while (cin >> c_data) {

    if (c_data == predata) {
        cout << "the " << c_data << " is the same one" << endl;
        break;
    }   
    else {
        predata = c_data;
        c_data = "eof is setted";
    }   

    cout << "please input next word" << endl;
}   

if (c_data != predata)
    cout << "there's no repeated word" << endl;
```